# How to get best performance from views in MySQL

Tags: mysql

We got some views in our database and which are taking more time and having some performance issues. Can anyone suggest or recommend the best way of handling the views in performance aspect.

The below is the example format of views we are using:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM VIEW `v_UK_CM_Demands_Audit_History` 
 AS  select `UK_CM_Demand_Audit_History`.`demandAuditId` AS `demandAuditId`,
 `v_UK_CM_Consolidated_Generic_Demand_Details_Temp`.`genericDemandId` AS `genericDemandId`,
 `UK_CM_Demand_Audit_History`.`demandTypeId` AS `demandTypeId`,
 `v_UK_CM_Consolidated_Generic_Demand_Details_Temp`.`policyNumber` AS `policyNumber`,
 `v_UK_CM_Consolidated_Generic_Demand_Details_Temp`.`demandCreatedDateTime` AS `demandCreatedDateTime`,
 `UK_CM_Demand_Audit_History`.`transactionType` AS `transactionType`,
 `UK_CM_Demand_Audit_History`.`previousValue` AS `previousValue`,
 `UK_CM_Demand_Audit_History`.`currentValue` AS `currentValue`,
 `UK_CM_Demand_Audit_History`.`modifiedBy` AS `modifiedBy`,
 `UK_CM_Demand_Audit_History`.`modifiedDateTime` AS `modifiedDateTime` 
 from (`v_UK_CM_Consolidated_Generic_Demand_Details_Temp` 
  join `UK_CM_Demand_Audit_History`
  on((`v_UK_CM_Consolidated_Generic_Demand_Details_Temp`.`genericDemandId` = `UK_CM_Demand_Audit_History`.`genericDemandId`))) ;
```

Anyone suggest me the changes or improvements I need to make so that I can expect some better performance.
I am new to views so please give your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Please post the EXPLAIN and a schema for the tables in question.

Comment: Hi Neville,I have added the EXPLAIN

Comment: You are using a query that USES a view. You will have to add that query too. A view is just a way to abbreviate your query, it does not exist on its own, and the code will basically just be pasted to whereever you use it. So you will still have to optimize your actual query (and the optimization can of course be different for different queries that use this view). Also, your `explain` output is unreadable, please make a table out of it.

Comment: Can you please format it so it's legible?

Comment: Can have look please

Answer (score 0):

According to explain, neither table has any indexes.

If you can execute the following, it *should* speed things up:

```
create index genericDemandId on v_UK_CM_Consolidated_Generic_Demand_Details_Temp(genericDemandId);
create index genericDemandId on UK_CM_Demand_Audit_History(genericDemandId);
```